# Getting different results in PHP and JS when bit shifting

Tags: php, javascript, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm getting some odd results where 2 identical functions (one in PHP and one in javascript) are returning different results.

The input for both of these lines of code is identical:

```
a = 4653896912;
b = 13;
```

I have double checked the variable types and both variables are numbers in JS and integers in PHP.

The line of code for PHP is this:

```
$a = $a >> $b;
```

For Javascript it's this:

```
a = a >> b;
```

You'd expect **a** to have the same value after both, but I'm getting the following:

```
PHP: $a = 568102
JS: a = 43814
```

Which has completely baffled me at this point.

---

Turns out this is definitely an issue of PHP using 64 bit integers and JS only using 32 bit. The problem I face now is that I need to get PHP to use 32-bit integers for these calculations. I found a function someone else wrote that looks like it should work, but it doesn't seem to be changing the output at all for me.

```
private static function toInt32(&$x) {
    $z = hexdec(80000000);
    $y = (int) $x;
    if($y ==- $z && $x <- $z){
        $y = (int) ((-1) * $x);
        $y = (-1) * $y;
    }
    $x = $y;
}
```

Comment: Well the PHP ones looks like the right result for a '>>' as bitwise right shift.

Comment: Hey Brian, the size of an integer is platform-dependet. Take a look at the PHP manual. http://de3.php.net/integer ... could you give some more information about your system? 32bit? 64bit? type of browser and your php version? thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all the input, it's definitely an issue of my server being 64-bit. The problem now is that I need to find a way to force PHP to run these calculations while limiting it to 32 bit integers so that the results will match up with the ones from JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code demonstrates masking the upper 32 bits of the number to retrieve only the lower 32 bits to use in your calculations.  4294967295 is 2^32 - 1.  I think that if you mask all values that could be greater than 32 bits in this manner, then you can get the same results from your php and javascript.

```
<?php
    $php_a = 4653896912;
    $php_b = 13;

    //convert $php_a into a 32 bit val
    $php_a = $php_a & 4294967295;

    $a = $php_a >> $php_b;
    echo "PHP: \$a = $a <br />";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = 4653896912;
    var b = 13;

    var a = a >> b;
    alert('Javascript A value is ' + a);
</script>
```

Comment: I love you. You're not the dog, you're the man man! That just did it :D

Answer (score 0):

4653896912 is more than 32 bits.. unpredictable results are likely. I get `$a = 43814` for PHP, but that is actually 358929617 >> 13, so in all likelihood PHP is doing 64 bit operations but JavaScript is only 32 bit.

Comment: You know what... I hadn't considered that lol I guess I'll try to find a way to make PHP do the calculations in 32 bit so the results match up. Thanks ;)

Comment: until you run across a client machine that's running a 64 bit browser.

Comment: ECMAScript logical operations are DEFINED as 32-bit operations.See  http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.7

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're `a` is above the limit of a 32-bit signed integer for [PHP][1].

The highest value possible is about 2 million, and `a` is over 4 billion.

When you're rolling over because of space limitations, results can be unpredictable (or at least, very difficult to figure out).

If your server is on a 64-bit version of PHP then it'll max out much higher than than, but javascript is limited by what the end-user is running.

You can read up on PHP on their [integers page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).